# How to validate jump 24h/48h/72 in Brussels?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, brussels

I have some doubts abut validation Brussels jump card 24h/48h/72h .

1. If I buy one of these cards I should validate it for the first time in the red machine with white eye?
2. And then I am not sure if I should validate this card every time I board a tram?
3. And when I get off the tram I also should insert this card into orange machine in the tram?

Could someone help me because it seems a bit complicated when i try find information on the internet.

Comment: For most time-limited tickets in most places, you validate once to start the time-period, and never again. If the validator prints the time on the ticket, validating twice will make it illegible. But I don't know the Brussels system.

Answer (score 4):

JUMP tickets are the classical paper tickets with a magnetic strip. They look like this:

[image]

They have to be validated at the beginning of each journey, so each time you enter the metro or board a tram or bus. They don't have to be validated upon exit.

JUMP tickets have to be inserted into the orange machines. The "red machine with the white eye" is for the newer [MOBIB](http://www.stib-mivb.be/Basic.html?l=fr) tickets.

[image]

Here is an extract from the [STIB's official website](http://www.stib-mivb.be/DiscoverBrussels.html?l=en):

> Users must validate their transport ticket prior to every journey. At
>   above-ground stops, the transport ticket must be validated every time
>   the user boards or connects to a bus or tram. In underground metro and
>   pre-metro stations, users must validate their transport tickets in the
>   inspection areas.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply but I am still a bit confuse. Maybe you will be able to clarify this sybject.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply but I am still a bit confused. Maybe you will be able to clarify this sybject. As I have read on the STIB website I understand that jump tickets 5/10 journeys are paper tickets with magnetic stripe and should be validate every time I board the tram/bus. But when I read about the jump tickets 24h/48h/72h i have an impression that I am supposed to validate it for the first time in the STIN network (if  it means the red machine ) . I have no idea if I am supposed to validate this kind of tickets every time I board a bus/tram. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Yes the 24/48/72 hours jump tucket has to be validated for each ride, just as you would do with a 5 or 10 journeys Jump ticket.